# How do I get the login link?

Tags: 7, users

I have a backup of a Drupal 7 website with its database. Is there any solution to get the login path? I have tried many options: /?q=user/login, /login, /user, and /user/login.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Can you clarify what do you need exactly - do you need this to create a link, or you are trying to login to the website?

Comment: use drush command "drush uli" to get one time login link

Comment: @AramBoyajyan yes i'm trying to login but i can't find the login path .

Comment: @user15837 thx, i'll try this command :)

Comment: @user15837 thx drush command work ;)

Comment: cool!!! @ Grub_elm

Answer (score 3):

use drush command to login, it will print the login URL.

```
drush uli;
```